# Variable is empty in bash

Tags: bash

Look at this code:

```
    find /Api -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1  |
    while read DependencyPath;
    do
        DependencyName=$(basename $DependencyPath);
        DependencyOrganization="Api";
        echo $DependencyOrganization - $DependencyName;
    done
```

This is the output:

```
 - Courses
 - Media
 - Orders
 - Blog
```

The first variable (`DependencyName=$(basename $DependencyPath);` is set. However, the second variable (`DependencyOrganization="Api"`) is not set.

I have no clue why it is not set. I also tried it using `bash -x /script` and this is the log:

```
+ find /Api -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1
+ read DependencyPath
++ basename /Api/Courses
+ DependencyName=Courses
+ DependencyOrganization=Api
+ echo - Courses
- Courses
+ read DependencyPath
++ basename /Api/Media
+ DependencyName=Media
+ DependencyOrganization=Api
+ echo - Media
+ read DependencyPath
- Media
```

I also tried `DependencyOrganization=$(echo "Api")` but it does not work.

What should I do?

**Update**
I'm running inside a container. After `docker exec -it container_name bash` If I run `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read temp; do name=hi; echo $name; done` directly inside the bash, it works. But if I save it in a file and run it as `./script` then it prints empty.

Comment: If it were me, I'd assume I'd made a spelling error in `$DependencyOrganization` so that it's expanding to nothing

Comment: Try running the code under `set -xv` to get more details, or under `set -u` to get an error when using an uninitialised variable.

Comment: It's not going to fix the problem as described, but double-quote your variables when you use them. For example, `basename "$DependencyPath"`. Also you might like to know that you can get the last component of a path directly in the shell with `${DependencyPath##*/}`

Comment: @steeldriver, yes that can be the source of the problem. But I opened the file in VS Code and visuall made sure no spelling error exist there. You can select an item and it highlights all items.

Comment: @choroba can you please explain more? where should I write that `set -xv`?

Comment: Error can't be reproduced. I get perfect results.

Comment: Insert the `set` line before the start of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This was the problem.

Our script (which is a build script) was generated dynamically. Inside that script-generation process, a step was like this:

```
envsubst < /path/to/script/template > /path/to/generated/script
```

This means that any variable that is used inside the script template would be replaced by `envsubst` to an empty value.

For example, if you have `Name=John; echo $John;` this would be turned into `Name=John; echo ;` in the generated script.

Since our generated script would be run inside a docker image, we had no idea that this was the problem. We assumed that it's just the script template with some parameters being set dynamically. However, when we investigated, it became clear that the problem was the `envsubst`.

Thus you should use it this way:

```
# This line is for envsubst. It won't be expanded, since it's single quotes
Name='$Name'
envsubst < /path/to/script/template > /path/to/generated/script
```

Comment: So the script you have posted in the question body is fine(ish); it's just different from the script you actually run. Oh well… It's good you have figured it out.

Comment: sounds like a (rare) case where `set -v` might have helped, it tells the shell to "Print shell input lines as they are read." (as opposed to `-x` which prints stuff when it's actually executed)